# How to print from the field separator ":" until end of the line?

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed, perl

How to print from the field separator ":" until end of the line

example:

```
echo " llap_java_opts  :  -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch {% if java_version > 7 %}-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:TLABSize=8m -XX:+ResizeTLAB -XX:+UseNUMA -XX:+AggressiveOpts"

llap_java_opts  :  -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch {% if java_version > 7 %}-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:TLABSize=8m -XX:+ResizeTLAB -XX:+UseNUMA -XX:+AggressiveOpts
```

expected output:

```
-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch {% if java_version > 7 %}-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:TLABSize=8m -XX:+ResizeTLAB -XX:+UseNUMA -XX:+AggressiveOpts
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `cut -d: -f2-` for this:

```
echo " llap_java_opts  :  -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch {% if java_version > 7 %}-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:TLABSize=8m -XX:+ResizeTLAB -XX:+UseNUMA -XX:+AggressiveOpts" | cut -d: -f2-
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass it through

```
sed 's/^[^:]*: *//'
```

This `sed` substitution will delete everything from the beginning of the line up to and including the first `:` and any spaces after it.

If you have the string in a shell variable `$a` then

```
printf -- '-%s\n' "${a#*-}"
```

This uses the parameter expansion `${parameter#word}` to delete everything up to and including the first `-`.  The dash is inserted again by the `printf`. This does not use any external utilities when run in most modern shells.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep`:

```
grep -Po ':\K.*' infile
```

the `\K` assertion will ignore to printing everything before and first colon `:` seen.